# C# Simple Combo Box Output

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox

I'm struggling with this practice assignment. I'm very new to programming and am fairly frustrated with this. I've researched multiple sites. Hope anyone can help!

I need to create a WindowsFormApp with 2 ComboBoxs having 2 values each. When a button is pressed the output in the Label on the form needs to show a unique sentence, depending on which combination of selected fields the user selected in the ComboBoxs.

Comment: Have you try something ? What do you want to write ? What contains your combo boxes ?

Comment: Combobox1 needs 2 values let's say "Red" and "Blue" and combobox2 needs the text "Yes" and "No", depending on the combination of selected values the text box needs to say something like "Blue is the sky; and yes its cloudy" depending on the selected values in the comboboxes.

Comment: Do you have any language ? Does your combo boxes have a name ?

Comment: using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Assignment_1._1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            cmbMode.Items.Add("Flashing");
            cmbMode.Items.Add("Steady");
            cmbColour.Items.Add("Blue");
            cmbColour.Items.Add("Red");

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your bouton click method :

```
Object selectedMode = cmbMode.SelectedItem;
Object selectedColour = cmbColour.SelectedItem;

YourLabelName.Text = selectedMode.ToString() + " " + selectedColour.ToString();
```

[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t14e0ws8.aspx) for more details